# Jquery Mobile scroll ón drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll

What i am trying to achieve is to dó a drag scroll In a div with overflow:hidden. I am making a board game and Would like clients ón handheld devices to drag scroll around The game board like In wordfeud etc. I tried kinect plugin which does The job, The only problem is that i am not allowed to click, since it treats it as a drag. Does anyone Gere have a Nice fix or another Way to achieve this?
Pardon if any details Are missing. Writing ón phone.

Thanks In advance.
Jonas